# Meaning of "$PWD":/path/to/directory"

Tags: linux, bash, docker

In docker I run the `docker run` with the following parameter: `-v "$PWD":/usr/src/app`. I know that `-v` specify where to mount the volume and `pwd` returns my current path. However, what does the `"$PWD:"` mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PWD is an environment variable that your shell will expand to your current working directory. So in this example, it would mount the current working directory, from where you are executing this command, to /usr/src/app inside your container.

E.g. assuming your current working directory is /home/youruser/somedir, your command line will be expanded to this by your shell before it is executed:

```
-v /home/youruser/somedir:/usr/src/app
```

The double quotes are there to escape special characters you might have in your current working directory's name, such as spaces.

Comment: Understood, @Stragulus. You know docker, right? If with this command specify the working directory, I could say that an extra parameter `-w /usr/scr/app` in `docker run` call is redundant?

Comment: No, the environment variable is expanded by the shell (docker only sees the expanded version).

Comment: Will this variable work on all of Windows, Linux, and Mac?